# ODE with functional argument

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

I am trying to find a closed form solution for this ODE: $(a_0+a_1x)f(x)+(b_0x+b_1x^2)f^\prime (x) = (c_0+c_1x)f(d_0+d_1x)$. It is not a simple ODE due to the $f(d_0+d_1x)$ term. I also found a related subject as the delayed functional ODE that allows terms like $f(x-d_0)$. Is there any approach to find a closed form solution for this problem? Thanks for your advise.

Comment: use the Fourier transform and the shifting and the scaling properties of it, this will give you a second-order ode with exponential coefficients.

Comment: Would you please explain more?

Answer (score 0):

By a linear change of variables, we may assume $d_0 = 0$.  Then if we assume a formal series solution of the form 
$$ f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty A_k x^{k+p} $$
we get a recursion for the coefficients
$$ (a_0 + (k+p) b_0 - c_0 d_1^{k+p}) A_k + (a_1 + (k+p-1) b_1 - c_1 d_1^{k+p-1}) A_{k-1} = 0, \ k \ge 1 $$
with $(a_0 + p b_0 - c_0 d_1^p) A_0 = 0$.  For a nonzero solution, we'll want to choose $p$ so that $a_0 + p b_0 - c_0 d_1^p = 0$.  This can be solved using the Lambert W function:

$$p = -\frac{W\left(-\dfrac{\ln(d_1) c_0}{b_0} d_1^{-a_0/b_0}\right)}{\ln(d_1)}  -{\frac {a_{{0}}}{b_{{0}}}}
$$

Comment: Thank you, but the linear change of variables also affects the left hand side. Would you please explain more and how you derive the recursion? I expect to have a power series expansion  for f(x), but did not think a bout parameter $p$?

Comment: Let  $f(x) = g(t)$ where $t = x - x_0$ for some constant $x_0$.  The equation becomes $$(a'_0 + a_1 t) g(t) + (b'_0 + b_1 t) g'(t) = (c'_0 + c_1 t) f(d'_0 + d_1 t)$$
where $a'_0 = a_0 + a_1 x_0$, etc.

Comment: You choose $x_0$ so that $d'_0 = 0$.

Comment: And then the recursion comes from looking at the coefficient of $t^{k+p}$ in the equation.

Comment: Thanks so much, but as I am not familiar with this sort of DE I can't understand the relationship between $i$ and $k$ in the recursion.

Comment: Oops: typo (corrected).  The $i$ was supposed to be $k$.